# comparison between iphone OS 3.0 and 3.1.3?

Tags: iphone

i want to know in Detail comparison between iPhone OS 3.0 and 3.1.3 and also want to to about all newly added features in OS 4.0 so please give a link or some source which gives the comparison and Newly added features in details with Description.

Comment: i know but i want some specific answer with points listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the [version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_OS_version_history) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone OS 4.0 is still under NDA. I can't provide you with the details of the changes, but any result Google will return is spot on.

The changes between iPhone OS versions which have been released are available on [the iPhone developer site.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone)